# SQL Server 2014: Convert and save location coordinates

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I want to save coordinates to SQL Server.

```
Decimal latitude, longitude;

String[] location = txt_coord.Text.Split(',');
latitude = Convert.ToDecimal(location[0]);
longitude = Convert.ToDecimal(location[1]);
```

Using LINQ to save

```
tbl_location loc = new tbl_location();
loc.ID = personal.id_personalinfo;
loc.latitude = latitude;
loc.longitude = longitude;

db.tbl_locations.InsertOnSubmit(loc);

db.SubmitChanges();
```

Error actually occurs on the conversion, I used the `decimal(18, 9)` data type in SQL Server. Error is:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Does this mean that the string itself is the error...!?

Also, is it right to use decimal for coordinates? should I use geography (internet says LINQ does not support this data type.)

Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you are getting indicates that `Convert.ToDecimal(...)` is failing because of invalid input parameters.

The value of either `location[0]` or `location[1]` is not what you expect it to be (if this is where the exception occurs).

Comment: i found out the error, the locations weren't able to pass to code behind because of a postback caused by a modalPopup, I found an alternate way to avoid the postbacks, thanks for telling me.